# Stack level too deep on sequel eager load

Tags: mysql, ruby, irb, sequel

I'm attempting to eagerly load a relatively large table using the Sequel ORM to test the amount of results I get based on using different key conditions:

```
a = Eqmifsequel.eager(:paauditsequels).all
```

The relationship looks like this:

```
one_to_many :paauditsequels, :primary_key => [:serial_number,:customer_number], :key => [:serial_number,:cust]
```

The tables are the following sizes

```
eqmifsequel : 69357 records
paauditsequel : 8648976 records
```

When I run the line of code at the top, I get a 'stack level too deep' error. I've tried upping my ulimit stack size (up to 1GB), but that doesn't seem to change anything.

I'm guessing I'm doing something bad, but I don't have the knowledge (math, cs, hardware) to know what or why.

Can anyone give me some suggestions? Is there a way I can calculate how much stack space I'm about to use when I try to join and return two large tables? Does this have to do with how Sequel is creating the join? If it were to succeed, would I end up crashing my system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haha, yeah. When you call .all it will return the entire data set in a single block.

Whatever you were planning on doing with the data that's the wrong approach. If you're trying to iterate through everything use .find_each like so:

```
Eqmifsequel.joins(:paauditsequels).find_each do |i|
  # something
end
```

If you're only interested in the number of results:

```
Eqmifsequel.joins(:paauditsequels).count
```

Comment: Hmm, I get a no method error when I use .find_each, and from the documentation, you must use .all to use .eager. When I do that even for one_to_one relationships of about 65K records, I still get stack errors. Any ideas on how large the tables can be before I run out of space to eagerly load?

Comment: don't eager load that much data, ever. you can still use a `join`. I've updated my answer.